# Ordenar um SELECT em MySql por uma letra

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, back-end, order-by

Como posso fazer uma query SELECT em MySQL que ordene os resultados e apresente inicialmente os que começam com uma letra especifica?

Ex com a letra P:
Paulo
Patricia (1º os que começam pela letra)
Filipe (2º os que têm a letra no meio)

Comment: Selecionar registros começando pela letra: `Select * From tabela WHERE nome Like "P%"` - Selecionar registros que tenha a letra no meio: `Select * From tabela WHERE nome Like "%P%"`

Comment: Boa tarde, tente isso: $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pessoa where nome like = 'a%' AND nome like = 'b%' ORDER BY nome ASC");

Answer (score 5):

Para isso pode usar `POSITION()` ou `LOCATE()` (são sinônimos)

```
SELECT   nome
FROM     pessoa
WHERE    LOCATE( 'p', nome ) > 0
ORDER BY LOCATE( 'p', nome );
```

Explicação: O position retorna a posição numérica da substring na string desejada, efetivamente ordenando pela proximidade do 'p' com a extremidade esquerda da string.

Manual:

> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_locate

O importante aqui é essa parte:

```
ORDER BY POSITION( 'p', nome );
```

pois, para saber se o 'p' está na string, poderia usar um `LIKE` ou outra função.

**Alternativa se quiser listar também os que não tem 'p':**

```
SELECT   nome
FROM     pessoa
ORDER BY LOCATE( 'p', nome ) = 0,
         LOCATE( 'p', nome );
```

Veja ambas funcionando no **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8a3c6f/1)**.

Answer (score 3):

Seleciona todos que começam com a letra P

```
SELECT * FROM suatabela WHERE coluna LIKE 'p%'
```

Letra do meio

```
SELECT * FROM suatabela WHERE coluna LIKE '%p%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Começando com letra P

```
..... ORDER BY CASE WHEN LEFT(NomeColuna, 1) = 'P' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, NomeColuna
```

Começando com letra P e depois com letra P em qualquer posição

```
 .... Order by case WHEN LEFT(NomeColuna, 1) = 'p' then 1 else 2 end
       , case when NomeColuna LIKE '%p%' then 1 else 2 end
```

ou ordenando melhor

```
.... Order by case WHEN LEFT(NomeColuna, 1) = 'p' then 1  else 2 end
   , case when NomeColuna LIKE '%p%' then 1 else 2 end, NomeColuna
```

> Nada foi dito quanto aos demais registros que não contém a letra `P`, portanto assumi que deveriam ser listados por ultimo. [**Exemplo SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ce682/1)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer isso de diferentes formas.
Vou mostras dois métodos:
1 - Através de `Union`

```
Select Nome,1 as ordem from tabela where Nome like 'P%'
union
Select Nome,2 as ordem from tabela where Nome like '%p%'  and Nome not like 'P%'
order by ordem, nome
```

O primeiro `Select` traz os nomes que começam com P e adicionamos um campo fixo com calor 1.
O segundo `Select` traz os nomes que tenham P em qualquer posição e que não comecem com P.

Depois só fazer o `union` e ordernar pelo campo `Ordem` e `Nome`

Veja funcionando no [SQL Fiddle exemplo 1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/949019/7).

2 - Usando um `Case` na clausula `Order By`

```
Select Nome from tabela where Nome like '%P%'
order by case when left(nome,1)='P' then 1 else 2 end, nome
```

Primeiro selecionamos somente os nomes que tenham a letra p em qualquer posição e depois criamos um critério de ordenação usando o Case. Para os nomes que tenham P na primeira posição o valor é 1 senão 2.

Veja funcionando no [SQL Fiddle exemplo 2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/949019/8).

## Nota:

Ao contrário do que foi dito em outras respostas `like '%p%'` não retorna os nomes que tenham P no meio da palavra. Essa comparação traz os nomes com P em qualquer posição. Veja: [SQL Fiddle Exemplo 3](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/949019/9)